# Calling a varible from a string

Tags: python, variables

I have some code like:

```
G = 'Hello!'
variable = input('Enter a letter').upper()
```

I then want the program to print `'Hello!'` when the user enters the letter G. How can I do this? Is `exec()` useful for the task? I saw some mentions of it, but I didn't understand how to use it.

Comment: [**Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Use `locals()`:

```
a = 'foo'
locals()['a']
'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, could you please explain what locals is - as I don't understand how this works

Comment: This is almost never the right solution.